# Formatted Json Deserialize throws Exception

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I was experiencing some to deserilize a **json file** until I realized the reason was that the file was formatted, prettified, beautified etc.

Using `Newtonsoft.Json` library and calling

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObject>(mystring);
```

`throws a JsonSerializationException`:

```
{"Unexpected end when reading JSON. Path '', line 1, position 1."}
```

Then, when I repeated the operation, but with a minified, compacted, etc version of the same file it worked.

Is there a way to use this libray and deserialize data in both scenarios?

Thank you!

Comment: could you provide the exact text which is not working?

Comment: this exception occurs for invalid json..share your json

Comment: Your json is correct can you show the myObject model in this code.

    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObject>(mystring);

Comment: I apretiate the effort to help me find errors in the json file and c# model, but my question was actually regarding the Newtonsoft.Json library. Is it capable of deserializing json string in both described scenarios?

Comment: I think the problem is still in your json data, because there is an example on the [homepage](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which deserializes a formatted json string.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is Valid, your model should be like this

```
public class Step
{
    public int StepID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<int> ShutMoves { get; set; }
    public List<int> FeatIDs { get; set; }
    public List<int> ExpSettings { get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
    public int PartID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Moving { get; set; }
    public List<int> FeatIDs { get; set; }
}

public class Feat
{
    public int FeatID { get; set; }
    public int CamID { get; set; }
    public int CamFeatID { get; set; }
    public int PartID { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    public List<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    public List<Feat> Feats { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Small Example -

```
public void JsonDeserializeTesting() {
    var testingModal = new TestingModal{Id = 1,Name = "Eminem",};
    var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testingModal);
    var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestingModal>
    (serializeObject);
    Console.WriteLine($"{deserializeObject}");
}
public class TestingModal{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I hope this will give you abstract view of how to use Deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake from my side. The string I was deserializing was obtained by using ReaLine(). So my code was parsing only the first line of the file.

ReadToEnd() from the stream or even File.ReadAllText fixes the issue.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I would suggest deleting the question at this point - *or* improving it. A question about a failure to parse JSON that doesn't show either the JSON or the model you're trying to parse it to, or how you're reading the JSON, is unlikely to be useful to a future user. (But you could definitely improve the question to show how you're reading the data - then it could be useful.)